TypeWriter React issue
In this snippet, I can't seem to understand why the vertical bar (|) doesn't appear for the "Hey, I'm Adam" portion, but does for the "Lorem ipsum..." text.
import React from "react";
import Typewriter from "typewriter-effect";

import styles from "./Hero.module.css";
import { getImageUrl } from "../../utils";


export const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          <Typewriter
          onInit={(typewriter) => {
            typewriter.typeString("Hey, I'm Adam").pauseFor(3000).start();
          }} 
          />
        </h1>
        <p className={styles.description}>
        <Typewriter
          onInit={(typewriter) => {
            typewriter.typeString("Lorem ipsum dolor ").pauseFor(3000).start();
          }} 
          />
        </p>

Tried playing around with both typewriter functions to see if it was because of 2 different processes at the same time was the root cause, but even alone the "Hey, I'm Adam" portion wasn't showing the vertical bar.

Hey, I did run your code and it seems that its working. Haven't put the css though as you did not include it there. Big chance this is the issue. Can you please also share your css files?

Yes figured it out, you are right. The issue was in the CSS, I ran the code without any CSS as you did and it worked fined. Thanks!!!
